# Not able to load static files in Pug althrough the static file directory has been set in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am building an application and I am trying to send an email that uses Pug as a template engine and I am having problems loading static files in my template. My code successfully sets the public folder of my project as the static one and I am able to access the content of the files in the browser.

However, the files are not loaded in my Pug template when I use a relative path with respect to the public directory. I also tried specifying their absolute path which actually works.

The directory structure of my application is:

```
app

+/public

  +/css

    style.css

  image.png

+/src

  +/client

  +/server

    +/templates

      +/verify

        html.pug

        text.pug

    +server.js
```

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + "/../../.env"});
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../', 'public')));

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const Email = require('email-templates');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.SENDER_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.SENDER_PASS
  },
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_stattls_auto: true
});

const email = new Email({
  transport: transporter,
  views: {
    root: './templates'
  },
  send: true,
  preview: false
});

email.send({
  template: 'verify',
  message:  {
    from: process.env.SENDER_EMAIL,
    to: '*email*',
    subject: 'Activise - Email Verification',
  },
  locals: {}
})
.then(() => console.log('EMAIL SENT'))
.catch(err => console.log("ERROR: " + err));

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server listening for requests on port 8080!'))
```

Here is my Pug code as well

**html.pug**

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title=title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/style.css" type="text/css")
    body
        .email-text
            img(src="/image.png", alt="Application logo")
```

Comment: try `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../../public')));`

Comment: Pug really isn't set up this way - it can easily include anything in your views directory but no others by default.  The static folder is really intended for static content like stylesheets and images that your server needs to simply pass to the browser without requiring middleware.  Do you have a good reason for not using node/express/pug in the standard way?

Answer (score 1):

in the server.js

change

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../', 'public')));
```

to

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

also change you pug to this

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path of the ***Public*** folder you have mentioned on the ***express.static*** middleware is correct. It is currently pointed to two directories back from the current server.js file.